# How to route signal to another application from a Sapphire Pro 24

Tags: mixing, osx

I have a microphone (Rode NT1) and guitar plugged into a Focusrite Sapphire Pro 24 running on OSX 10.10.2

I can monitor these inputs but want to route them to another application (Skype). Is it possible to route the signal to another application? I've tried copying to another Mix and also the Loopback setting.

At the OS level, the Sapphire is selected at both the input and output and also in Skype preferences.

For clarity, this question is not specifically about Skype but about how to route the Saffire mixer's input to another application on my system. I've looked at the Saffire Manual but can't see how to do this.

[image]

In this particular application, you can only select 'Saffire' as the input, not individual channels.

[image]

Comment: You might want to investigate [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) though I've never tried it for that type of setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plus 1 for soundflower.  Another option is to try to create an aggregate device Audio Midi Setup.  And try unmuting, assigning, turning up everything you can in the Saffire MixControl.  I notice you have Monitor outputs 3,4,5, and 6 turned off (red).  Sometimes 3/4 is what is considered the main output by other applications linked to MixControl for some reason. Another problem I have found is that the level of latency you can select in MixControl can screw up some applications.  After everything is unmuted and you are testing in skype, try each possible latency.

If this doesn't work, Soundflower is really simple to set up.  It's a utility for linking audio between applications.

Answer (score 0):

basically, when you use a software which can take an input from your sound card, you should be able to choose which of the inputs to use.

in skype, for example, you are able to choose the right sound card and then the input channel.  choose the one with the mic / guitar. 
You cannot, however choose more than one channel, usually.

Other than unmuting the channel on the Saffire mixer, there is nothing you should be doing there.  Use the mic / guitar to make sure the channel receives the signal and gain it properly, then go to your application and choose that channel.

NOTE that you are not routing into an application, but rather the application is using a property of your sound card.

**EDIT**

You have the added option of using a software driver like [JACK](http://www.jackaudio.org/)  which can do a lot of nice tricks for routing audio.

Comment: Thanks but you can only choose the interface in Skype, not individual channels.

Comment: @codecowboy actually you /can/ select the channel, you that while in a call.